# Почему вопросы в новом появляются в разное время с главной?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, дизайн

На странице вопросов (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions) новый вопрос появляется не в то же время, что и на главной (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Кеш? Почему такое разное поведение? В среднем разница появления в промежутке 30-60 секунд.